# steps to take after creating self signed certificate private key /csr on cpanel

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, cpanel, public-key-encryption

I have created `ssl crt/private key/csr` from `ssl/tls` manager from `cpanel` .

What is the next step/configuration I need to do ?

When I type in address bar only--> example.in it works but if its https://example.in it does not work .

What changes I need to do ? .I have tried many things have created keys/crt/csr 50 times but still I get the same error https://example.in/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage. also the certificate states that its in another name .But that's impossible as everything is created by drop down options in ssl manager so every data is correct.

Also there was empty .htaccess created .I filled it with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It redirects to https but I keep getting the error above .

Summary :

```
1. Should I add something in htaccess ?  

2. Create php in html which authorizes certificate which has the domain website(index.html)?  

3. Or something else ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ll also need a dedicated IP address, to separate the site from others on the shared hosting server. Make sure you have installed self-signed certificate successfully. you should have .key and .crt created from WHM >> Generate a SSL Certificate & Signing Request, and paste in text file.

Install a self-signed SSL certificate

1. In WHM, click “Install an SSL Certificate and Setup the Domain”.
2. Enter the domain name, account user name, and IP address for the certificate in the Domain, User, and IP Address fields.
3. Click “Fetch” to paste the .key and .crt files for the domain into the available display spaces, if they are currently on your server.
4. Don’t enter anything in CA bundle: there is no Certificate Authority because you are installing a self-signed cert.
5. Click “Submit”, then wait for all processes to complete. WHM will display various lines of information and finally display “Finished Install Process.. “
6. Point your web browser to https:// followed by the domain, to see your new SSL connection working.

If you don’t see the SSL commands in your WHM, it may be because you don’t have a dedicated IP on your account. Once you have a dedicated IP assigned to a domain, the SSL Certificate links/commands will appear in WHM.

Comment: Thank You for the response Sir.Can you tell me how to get to WHM from Cpanel.CUrrently I did everything from Cpanel if you can guide me through Cpanel instead of WHM it would be great.(I do not have login credentials for WHM only CPanel)

Comment: You can do this from Cpanel from "SSL/TLS Manager" options in the "Security" section. But first of all make sure you have dedicated IP, Have you ? If you have then you should DNS setup as your website points to your dedicated IP.

Comment: I have not seen dedicated ip option in cpanel.I guess its somewhere else.Also Security section does not exist in ssl/tls manager in cpanel.Do I need to activate dedicated ip from the host provider ???

Comment: Yes, You should purchase dedicated IP, For this contact with your hosting provider, they can also do it for you.